# Не отправляются заголовки header

Tags: php

Не понимаю в чем может быть дело. Подскажите пожалуйста.

В скрипте делаю вывод заголовков.

```
$modified_date = strtotime('2023-02-09 17:25:05');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $modified_date).' GMT');
```

Если после этого идет сразу exit то заголовок выдается.

Дальше идет вывод кэша из файла.

```
$cacheFile = '/cache.txt';
$html  = file_get_contents($cacheFile); 
echo $html;
exit;
```

сразу пропадает строка Last-Modified.

Ответ сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.1
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2023 07:44:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.24
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Не понимаю как file_get_contents может отменять заголовок. headers_list() заголовок показывает.

Comment: и почему вы думаете, что заголовок пропадает на уровне пхп, а не nginx ?

Comment: Обрезаются заголовки после echo. даже если echo '1'; exit; то уже нету заголовков.

Comment: заголовок можно передавать только если не было еще вывода. Поэтому проверяйте возможность отправки заголовка ф-цией https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Comment: @aleksey-vaganov проверял. Ничего не отправляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам. Не очень дружу с настройкой серверов, так что могу наврать, у меня сработало. Может кому поможет, если вылезет в поиске. ngnix резал заголовок.
В ispmanager в разделе "сайты" есть пункт файлы конфигурации. Там отредактировал файл **ngnix.conf** добавив строку **ssi_last_modified on;**

Comment: Вы в вопросе писали, что в одном случае заголовок отдается, а в другом нет. При одинаковых настройках вебсервера он резал бы заголовки всегда.

Comment: Ну вот как то сработало. Я пробовал по разному. Вот если есть echo то нету заголовка, если без echo, а пустая страница, то есть загловок. Добавил эту строку и заработало.